# Can some one help me fix this list sorting code?

Tags: python

When I run this code it doesn't print anything?
I've tried to invert the greater than less than but it's not helping.

```
def is_sorted(numbers):
    ''' Return whether or not the list of numbers is sorted '''

    for i in numbers:
        if numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1]:
            print('True')
        else:
            print('False')
```

Comment: All this code does is define a function - why would you expect it to print anything?  You'd have to actually call this function, passing some list of numbers as a parameter, for anything to happen.

Comment: Both of the issues with this code are long-standing duplicates.  Since others have already explained both problems, I'll simply trust that your issues are solved, and vote to delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in numbers` in this case `i` is each number itself, **not** the index of each number. That would be `for i in range(len(numbers))` though then `[i + 1]` would go out of bounds on the last iteration.

As an alternative, I would simplify that function to compare each element to the next element by zipping a slice of the list against another slice offset by one. By writing this as a generator expression within `all` this will short-circuit upon hitting the first `False`

```
def is_sorted(numbers):
    return all(i <= j for i, j in zip(numbers, numbers[1::]))
```

For example

```
>>> is_sorted([1,3,5,7])
True
>>> is_sorted([1,6,2,7,3])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```py
def is_sorted(numbers):
    isSorted = True
    for i in numbers:
        try:
            if i > numbers[numbers.index(i)+1]:
                isSorted = False
        except:
            pass
    return isSorted
    
print(is_sorted([1,2],3,9,3))
```

You should add the variable, `isSorted`, because if `i > next number`, it would print `False`, but if `i < next number`, it would print `True`. You need the `try` and `except`, because if there was an error, if it was on the last number, it would be ignored. You also need to change `i > numbers[i+1]` to `i > numbers[numbers.index(i)+1]`, because to get the next number, we need to add 1 to the index, not the value.